# XAML C# possible Slider value shall depend on other Slider's value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my App there are two sliders that shall define a range (interval of values). But the second slider must not have a value <= then the value of the first slider. Is there a possibility to add this constraint directly into the XAML code?

Here is the XAML definition of the first slider:

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider_Brightness"  Minimum="0" Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.05" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Width="100" Margin="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Value="0.5"  />
```

And the second slider is:

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider_BrightnessEnd"  Minimum="0" Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.05" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Width="100" Margin="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Value="0.5" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CB_BrightnessRange, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

Here is a screenshot how it looks on the UI.

[image: Sliders on App UI]

As you can see, Slider 2 is only active, if the Range CheckBox is enabled. The text boxes are binded to the vlaue of the sliders.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Define "messes up the sliders" binding works good for me

Comment: It shifts the minimum value of the slider and the frequency does not fit anymore

Comment: Why don't you bind `Maximum` property of 2nd Slider with `Value` property of 1st slider? Why are you playing with `IsEnabled` property which has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: @emoacht you mean binding Minimum property right? This works but looks ugly.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by ugly.

Comment: @emoacht The IsEnabled property is linked to the Checkbox because it shall be possible to use a single value or a range. Sorry, I thought that may be obvious. And you are right, t has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Binding the Minimum property of Slider 2 to Value of Slider 1 will work but may look ugly.

A really nice solution is described here:
[WPF slider with two thumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395957/wpf-slider-with-two-thumbs?rq=1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).